# Как сделать удаление смахиванием в android

Tags: java, android, xml

Есть какая-то строка, как сделать анимацию смахивания, чтобы оно уезжало влево и удалялось (функционал удаления есть, но просто на кнопке)?

Comment: В гугле миллион примеров ведь. Вбивайте в поиск "android recyclerview swipe to remove" и смотрите)

Comment: @АндроидАндроид [Не отправляйте спрашивающих в поисковики](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2013/213987).

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/672631/177345

Comment: я не знал, как это правильно называется

Answer (score 0):

Можешь использовать ItemTouchHelper. Вот как [пример](https://devcolibri.com/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-part-1/).

Comment: Своевременный ответ был бы кстати. Вопрос уже не актуален.